# wget is not downloading files from subdomains

Tags: pdf, wget, subdomain

I want to download pdf files from a domain. some files are hosted on the subdomain. How could I make wget download from subdomains?

Ex: i am trying to download files from this [website](http://www.belkin.com/us/support-search?q=document:rank&show=All), where files are hosted on cache-www.belkin.com, whereas actual website is hosted on www.belkin.com. How could I solve this?

The command used is :

> wget -r -D www.belkin.com,cache-www.belkin.com --tries=0 --continue 
>   -l1 -A pdf -e robots=off -U mozilla http://www.belkin.com/us/support-search?q=document:rank&show=All

Comment: some ideas - there is -H but it'd go too far..   also I don't think wget supports wildcards.. and perhaps neither does curl ..  You are only trying to go `-r -l 1`, i.e. links to a depth of one, so you could  use grep to find all the links on the page, then get a file with all the links you want. Then `wget -i fileofurls`   and wget `-t 1 -T 5 -w 1` is always good for not burdening the server and not getting banned by the server.

Comment: for example sake, i gave level 1. there are some use cases where i want to go little deeper. i tried -H but it is becoming uncontrollable.

Comment: I guess one way would be to write a program that does wget on a page, greps it to get the URLs, greps it to filter it for URLs being on the wanted subdomain(s),  and repeats that depending on what depth you want.(not sure if that should or has to be recursive rather than iterative, it may take some fiddling to make sure it doesn't go into an infinite loop and that it gets all that you want and no more), but once you have the program working then have a list of all the URLs you want then the wget -i on it.

Answer (score 2):

```
wget -Hr -Dwww.belkin.com,cache-www.belkin.com --tries=0 --continue -l1 -A pdf -e robots=off -U mozilla http://www.belkin.com/us/support-search?q=document:rank&show=All
```

Explanation: -D must be used with -H and no space is allowed